# Single assemby in using statement

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies

I'm working on app which uses a lot of external assemblies (newtonsoft.dll, Yahoo Yui compressor.dll, fleck.dll etc). In each c# file I need to add using statement with all those assemblies. Is it possible to create my own assembly (i.e. LIBRARY.dll) containing all the dll's and refer only to this in all c# files?

Comment: You're confusing assemblies and namespaces. Using directives (not using statements - they're the ones which automatically call `Dispose`) are about *namespaces*, not assemblies. A single assembly can contribute to multiple namespaces, and vice versa.

Comment: Buy ReSharper ... you won't regret it!

Comment: @Jammer meh; the IDE supports namespace resolution / directive adding without needing extra tools

Comment: Sure it does but ReSharper is still a great too imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Firstly, `using` *directives* refer to *namespaces*, not assemblies (assembly references are defined at the project level). Secondly: you almost certainly don't actually need *all* of them in every file. But: you can create a new-file-template with the ones you are likely to need. But frankly it is usually easier to either copy/paste them, or just add them when they are needed. In the IDE, this is as simple as pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>,<kbd>ret</kbd> after a type name that doesn't resolve... so `MySpecialType`<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>,<kbd>ret</kbd> should add the missing `using` directive to resolve `MySpecialType`.

Comment: Awesome answer as per usual :)

Answer (score 1):

`using` does not refer to assembly, but to namespace. So the answer is "no"...

```
using System; // you are using items in the System namespace
using System.IO; // you are using items in the System.IO namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Usages of individual types need to be resolved to the namespaces where they are defined in. So, you will still need to include the resolution paths in your usings.